# Internal DNS name for sharepoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, url

I want to be able to connect to SharePoint Online using a custom URL, Ex; **intranet.domain.se**.

Simply creating a cname record to redirect traffic doesn't work since SharePoint online uses the URL to route sharepoint requests to the right companies sharepoint site (intrernally at microsoft).

So even though **intranet.domain.se** points to **domain.sharepoint.com** in our internal DNS, microsoft can't route the traffic to our sharepoint site since the cname in the URL is not readable for their IIS server.

Instead I'm routed to their front end webservers (WFE's) status page.

Anyone know if there is any magical way to make this work?
Preferably without using IIS or any other webserver to redirect traffic.